# Is there any intuitive way to see $\frac{e^{\delta}}{(1+\delta)^{1+\delta}}\leq e^{-\delta^2/3}$ $0<\delta<1$

Tags: probability, inequality, large-deviation-theory

I am reading the proof of Chernoff bound ,there's one step here :
$$\frac{e^{\delta}}{(1+\delta)^{1+\delta}}\leq e^{-\delta^2/3}$$
where $0<\delta<1$

the book prove that by using the second order dervative analysis of

$$f(\delta)=\delta -(1+\delta)log(1+\delta)+\frac{\delta^2}{3}$$

but how to see this upper bound for$\frac{e^{\delta}}{(1+\delta)^{1+\delta}}$  or is there any straight inequality manipulation to get there?

Comment: The inequality is false for $\delta=2$. Do you have a restricted range of $\delta$ in mind?

Comment: @GregMartin thank you are right , I already fixed it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of comparing
$$\frac{e^{\delta}}{(1+\delta)^{1+\delta}}\leq e^{-\delta^2/3}$$
take logarithms and prove that 
$$\delta -(1+\delta ) \log (1+\delta ) < -\frac{\delta^2}3$$
Expanded as series built around $\delta=0$, the lhs is 
$$-\frac{\delta ^2}{2}+\frac{\delta ^3}{6}-\frac{\delta ^4}{12}+O\left(\delta
   ^5\right)$$ Now, use the fact that $\delta<1$ making
$$-\frac{\delta ^2}{2}+\frac{\delta ^3}{6} \le -\frac{\delta ^2}{2}+\frac{\delta ^2}{6}=-\frac{\delta ^2}{3}$$